# Create custom keyboard in android using different layout and keys not being rectangle, shape picked from the drawable image

Tags: java, android, view, keyboard, android-custom-view

I have tried to use the custom keyboard in android. I tried the following links 
[Custom keyboard - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676566/custom-keyboard-android)

I have also tried to create a custom keyboard using [Android Custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646580/android-custom-keyboard) link.

All these have a custom keyboard, but it uses the default key pattern of android.

I would like to create a keypad without such look and feel.

I want to create a keyboard with a key having occupied two rows in a column whereas some can occupy a space of 4 keys(2x2).

Example : 
https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtHoD_LfzD4AepsAffO2WQbMYzWlQdymMWAXqz47s8EwvryYNW

Look at the enter key in this keyboard.

Also, I want to use drawable images that can be used as the key, which can have wierd design. I would want to create the image shape depending on the png image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) and specified a source file for the `drawable` image.

This helped me with the image on the button, but the button still occupied a rectangle section. To remove the alpha region, I seeked help of the `android:background` property of [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) in android layout file.

```
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
```

Now, if you want to disallow button taps on those regions, you can refer the following link. 
[Hexagon button with hexagon touch area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110814/hexagon-button-with-hexagon-touch-area)

Answer (score 0):

You can try create custom layout and use it when you want to show soft keyboard. Here's a link explaining how you can detect show/hide keyboard action: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388539/3864698

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your suggestion QArea. But that was not what I was looking for.